# Excel Connection Manager in visual studio 2010

Tags: ssis

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'.
Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

i am also change the 64bit. eventhough it throughs the same error.

anybody solve this...?

Comment: Please provide enough information to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry "Tab Alleman" actually i got solution for this

Comment: Thanks for your responce "Tab Alleman"